# Using domain mail server for sendmail

Tags: smtp, localhost, sendmail

The piece of php script is:

## $sendmail=1;

## $sendmail_path='/path/to/sendmail';

$smtp_server='localhost';

My webhost want me to use my domain smtp mail server mail.xxxxx.net instead of "localhost" otherwise sendmail is blocked.
I don't know how to reset the script.
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: So... What's the problem? What happens if you change the `$smtp_server` value like your host has instructed?

Comment: The smtp mail path given by hogator ie. my host is:                                                  /home/username/mail/domain.tld/user's name.  I am using my smtp mail viz. info@telugugreetings.net. I gave the following path to the SMTP mail /home1/my domain user name/mail/myfull domain name/info  But I am getting the error that  SMTP server is not found at /home1/my domain user name/mail/telugugreetings.net/info  Kindly help me configure Thanks

Comment: Your SMTP server wouldn't be a file path on your server. That might be a valid setting for `$sendmail_path`, but `$smtp_server` should probably simply be a hostname like `mail.domain.net`, as you suggested in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the settings that you tried

```php
<?php

$smtp_server='mail.telugugreetings.net';
```

is actually a *correct setting*, as indicated by its error message:

> Additional errors: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

This is an SMTP error, so you have successfully connected to your SMTP server. This error indicates a [completely different problem](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt):

> ### 4.1.1.1  Extended HELLO (EHLO) or HELLO (HELO)
>
> These commands are used to identify the SMTP client to the SMTP server.  The argument field contains the fully-qualified domain name of the SMTP client if one is available.  In situations in which the SMTP client system does not have a meaningful domain name (e.g., when its address is dynamically allocated and no reverse mapping record is available), the client SHOULD send an address literal (see section 4.1.3), optionally followed by information that will help to identify the client system.  y The SMTP server identifies itself to the SMTP client in the connection greeting reply and in the response to this command.

Make sure that you are setting the "From" field properly. It should probably be something ending in `@telugugreetings.net`. Without knowing more about your mail server and your PHP code, including any libraries you may be using to send mail, I can't be more specific.

You might need to contact your hosting provider again to ask about this new error message.

Comment: Thank you. Since my host is not replying properly and non-coperative I want to use google smtp server for the purpose eventhough there are restrictions on number of mails to be sent. What codeshould I  use and where to put in my mail configuration file? Kindly help me and ease tension since my site is down for more than a month ever since my host changed servers. Thanks again

Comment: Using Gmail SMTP isn't a great idea for a number of reasons. You may need to update your DNS MX record for your domain. It should be set to `mail.telugugreetings.net`, to match your PHP setting.

Comment: Thanks   My host says that  we do not set rDNS or PTR record for shared hosting customers. I understand that mail relay as required in my case is not possible if this is not enabled. With my very little technical knowledge, I am not able to do anything. My understanding of things is very little. I am not able to follow technical details.

Answer (score -1):

The PHP manual's mail() Runtime configuration says:
**Used under Windows only: host name or IP address of the SMTP server PHP should use for mail sent with the mail() function.** 
[Click Here for PHP Mail Runtime configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php)

Is this on you local Windows machine? 
Are you hosting on a Windows machine? 
**If not Windows the SMTP directive is ignored.**

If you have a Windows machine:
The PHP setting for SMPT is a `"PHP_INI_ALL, Entry can be set anywhere"`
Which mean this directive can be set Runtime, in:

```
 php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini
```

Get you SMPT Configurations Setting:

```
echo ini_get('SMTP');
```

To Set you SMTP

```
ini_set ('SMTP', $SMPTServer)
```

**Where $SMPTServer** is the host name or IP address of the SMTP server PHP should use for mail sent.

Comment: Thanks Where to insert this code I tried earlier                                                                                           $smtp_server='mail.mysite.net';                                                                                But it has not worked

Comment: @pdurvasula, do you get a different error message here? You haven't given us enough code or other information to say what's wrong.

Comment: @Chris, Please see the linked text for code and error messages received on execution of the code:                                                                                                   http://telugugreetings.net/code.txt                                                                         Thanks

Comment: I included a link in my Answer that takes you to the PHP Manual with all the sendmail Runtime settings. You could put this in your PHP script ini_set ('SMTP', 'mail.mysite.net') or with your IP Address e.g. ('SMTP', '123.456.789') )